# Is Kategorie C music not allowed in Germany?

Tags: rock, bands

I know some of the band members are radical right, perhaps `neo nazis`. But their music sounds really good and its about football, but as a none German they might be hiding some political/racist chants which I am not aware of.

I know in one of their songs they have `ANTIFA HALTS MAUL` which is equivalent to `Shut up Anti Fascist`.

So my question is:

- Is their music OK ? or not allowed as other neo-nazi bands ?

Comment: Maybe you can provide a Band name or ask the authorities directly here: http://www.bundespruefstelle.de/

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr the band name is "Kategorie C"

Comment: Oh, I didn't recognise it as a band name, sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategorie_C_(Band)) the band is not forbidden. But it's a very right wing hooligan band with tight connections to fascist parties like NPD.

Their background are right hooligans, that's where the football part in their music comes from. But they are also celebrating Hitler and killing minorities:
"Hoch auf dem gelben Wagen, sitz ich beim Führer vorn, Vorwärts die Oi traben, lustig schmettert das MG“."

So:

> Is their music OK ?

Depends on your political views. If you're a right wing guy, Yes. Else, no.

> or not allowed as other neo-nazi bands?

I couldn't find any evidence that it is forbidden but you shouldn't run through Berlin singing their songs.

Comment: THANKS! that answers my question. I will stick to their songs which doesn't include racist sentences as the one you quoted. :) thanks!